# Как передать id из input в другой input

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap

[image: Пример]

Доброго времени суток , коротко говоря в *Оформить заказ* есть id-product, хочу передать его вызывающе modal окно.

Answer (score 0):

Не вижу проблемы. Сделай с помощью jQuery. Повесь обработчики событий на каждую кнопку, и при нажатие на нее бери атрибут id, и записывай в модальное окно.

```
$(document).on("click", ".delete-message", function(){ let attrId = $(this).attr("id"); $("#send").attr("id",attrId); });
```

Вроде так

Comment: Если в 3 строки есть то можно .

Comment: $(document).on("click", ".delete-message", function(){
let attrId = $(this).attr("id");
$("#send").attr("id",attrId);
});

Вроде так

Answer (score 0):

```js
//----------------------------------------------------------------
// Modal initializer
$('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
  $('#myInput').trigger('focus')
})
//----------------------------------------------------------------
// Event on Send 
$('#send').on('click', function() {
  //----------------------------------------------------------------
  // Get checked value example ... you can extend it as you like...
  //----------------- только для одного поля -----------------------
  //var checked = $('.modal-body').find('input:checked').val();// One checkbox
  //$('.modal-val').attr('value', checked);
  //----------------------------------------------------------------
  
  //------ Для всех полей которые checkbox -------------------------
  var checked = $('.modal-body').find('input:checked');
  
  $.each(checked, function (i, chk) { 
    // Выможете это делать по другому это один из возможных вариантов
    var v = $('.modal-val').val() 
    $('.modal-val').val($(chk).val() + ' , ' + v)
    
  })
  //----------------------------------------------------------------
  
  //console.log(checked);
})
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="//stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="form-check">
          <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="YourValue" id="defaultCheck1">
          <label class="form-check-label" for="defaultCheck1">
    Default checkbox
  </label>
        </div>

        <div class="form-check">
          <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="YourOtherValue" id="defaultCheck2">
          <label class="form-check-label" for="defaultCheck2">
    Default 2 checkbox
  </label>
        </div>

      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="send">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<input class="form-control modal-val" type="text" placeholder="Readonly input here…" value="" readonly>
```